# 404 - File or directory (a web.config file) not found - BUT FILE IS THERE

Tags: http-status-code-404

I enter my url and it shows the directory structure. There are some folders, which I can navigate to just fine, plus a Web.config file. I click the link and get the 404 error. The same thing happens for my Global.asax file. Why can't my file be found?

Answer (score 2):

You can't open them for security reasons.  You're not supposed to be able to open them in a browser.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.I have the same structure in local, ( this is a website of course) and it comes up fine, that is, my website home page displays. However, from the dev server, I see the dir structure and  not the website). Why might this happen?

Comment: Look for something like "<directoryBrowse enabled="true"> in the web.config file.  It turns on directory browsing.  Also make sure you have a default document set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use ASP.NET framework. IIS forbid the “http access” to these files.